# What should Black do?

Tags: problems, attack

I am reading “Ten Ways To Succeed In The Opening“ by Tim Onions and David Regis. On page 48, there is a problem I am trying to solve.

[image]

However, I can’t figure out what Black should do next.

Comment: Can white still castle?

Comment: @IanBush I’m not sure but suppose yes

Comment: I like qh4 but I don't think it's winning as such

Comment: I think it is ...Qh4, followed by ...Nf6, blocking the queen's escape diagonal, then get the b-pawn out of the way and play ...Bb7 winning the queen for a rook. I don't see a way for white to stop this plan, but it might be just me not seeing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel some doubt about this book. It is self-published by writers who are not well-known. I am sure they have in mind 1..Qh4 with some followup like 2 0-0 Nf6 3.h3 (to prevent Ng4) Bxh3 4.Qxa8 Qg3. A much better defence for White is 2. d4! and I do not think that Black is winning at all. If 2...Qxe4+ 3.Be3 and Black must prevent Qxh7 so 3...Nf6 4.dxc5 and White looks fine, or if 2...Bb6 3.Nd2 followed by Nf3. I dont think you need to reproach yourself with missing anything

Comment: After 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.Bxf7+? (Jerome Gambit) Kxf7 5.Nxe5+ Nxe5 6.Qh5+ g6 7.Qxe5 d6? 8.Qxh8 (the diagram position) Qh4 9.d4, Stockfish much prefers 9...Nf6 to 9...Qxe4+, though of course Black is still losing.